# cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argument - Cypress.env('StudentPortal')

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I'm trying to use Environment Variables via plugin method (https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/configuration-api#Switch-between-multiple-configuration-files), this has worked previously but recently has stopped working for me, any pointers would be great.

**plugin/index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('cypress', 'config', `${file}.json`)

  return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)
}


module.exports = (on, config) => {

  const file = config.env.configFile || 'build'

  return getConfigurationByFile(file)

}
```

**ConfigFile > build.json**

```
{
    "env": {
        "StudentPortal": "https://www.google.co.uk"
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
cy.visit(Cypress.env('StudentPortal'));
```

As I said, this used to work and would visit the URL within the configFile, now I just get the following error:

CypressError
cy.visit() must be called with a url or an options object containing a url as its 1st argumentLearn more
cypress/support/commands.js:17:8

15 |   Cypress.Commands.add('StudentPortalLogin', (email, password) => {
16 |

> 17 |     cy.visit(Cypress.env('StudentPortal'));

Comment: What does `console.log(Cypress.env)` and `console.log(Cypress.env())` show? What is the debug value of `fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile)`? Does it resolve the file path correctly?

Comment: I've used cy.log...prints:
Command:  log
cypress_runner.js:193332 Message:  {configFile: 'build'}

Comment: Did you put your build.json file under /cypress/config directory ?  should not be cypress/ConfigFile/ ?

Comment: With given data I couldn't reproduce the issue. Everything is working as expected. Make sure you are adding `build.json` file under `cypress/config/` path.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I managed to find out the issue, it wasn't the above code...

Someone had added this line for a second time to the bottom of the file which was causing the failure:

'module.exports = (on, config) => {'

Answer (score 0):

It appears the baseURL may be missing. `cy.visit()` is looking for something in reference to the baseURL. I don't see one defined in the build.json file, that might fix the error to add a baseURL, "https://www.google.co.uk", then put authentication parameters inside the env{} part, per the example in your link.